# Proof that this is a Cauchy Sequence

Tags: limits, cauchy-sequences

Let $(x_n)$ be a decreasing sequence in **R** with $x_n \geq 0$ for all $n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n} = 0$.

Define: $s_k = x_1 - x_2 + ... + (-1)^{k+1}x_k$.

Prove that $x_k$ is a Cauchy sequence thus proving that $(s_k)$ has a limit.

I'm not sure how to start this problem at all.

Comment: $(x_k)$ is Cauchy since it converges.

Comment: I think the exercise asks to prove that $(s_k)$ is a Cauchy sequence, not $(x_k)$.

Comment: If you meant to prove that $(s_k)$ is Cauchy: Try an example. Let $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ and look for bounded monotone subsequences of $(s_k)$.

Comment: Even so, you can just use the alternating series test right?

Comment: The alternating series test is pretty much what is to be proven here.

Comment: Yeah, basically a Dirichlet's test problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to prove that $| s_m - s_n |$ is definitely less than $\epsilon$.  Suppose $m>n$: then 
$$| s_m - s_n | = |x_1 - x_2 + \dots (-1)^{m+1}x_m - (x_1 - x_2 + \dots (-1)^{n+1}x_n) | = 
$$ 
$$|(-1)^{n+2}x_{n+1} + (-1)^{n+3}x_{n+2} + \dots (-1)^{m+1}x_m | \leq 
| x_{n+1} | < \epsilon.
$$ 
To see that 
$$|(-1)^{n+2}x_{n+1} + (-1)^{n+3}x_{n+2} + \dots (-1)^{m+1}x_m | \leq 
| x_{n+1} |
$$ 
just note that $x_n$ is positive and decreasing.
Now
$$ 
| x_{n+1} | < \epsilon
$$ 
because  $x_n$ converges to zero